# Cannot assign IP address according to an option parameter

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcp-option, dhcpd

I have this DHCP conf file:

```
authoritative;
option domain-name "XXX.XXX.XX";
allow bootp;
ddns-update-style ad-hoc;
class "karpuz-kabugu"
{
    match if (substring (option user-class, 0, 6) = "karpuz");
    log (info, "karpuz-kabugu");
}
        subnet 10.6.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  {
                pool {
                        range 10.6.1.10 10.6.1.99;
                        allow members of "karpuz-kabugu";
                }

                pool {
                        range 10.6.1.100 10.6.1.250;
                        allow unknown-clients;
                }

                option broadcast-address 10.6.1.255;
                option routers 10.6.1.1;

}
```

What I want to do is lease ip addresses according to user-class (option 77). I have set the user class id on my Windows DHCP client using `ipconfig /setclassid`

I also see `karpuz` set in DHCP Option 77 using wireshark.

The contents of the dhcp log is as the following:

```
May 27 17:09:18 2013 dhcpd: karpuz-kabugu
May 27 17:09:18 2013 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1c:23:b5:da:71 via eth4
May 27 17:09:19 2013 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.6.1.250 to 00:1c:23:b5:da:71 (DELL1-DESTEK) via eth4
May 27 17:09:19 2013 dhcpd: karpuz-kabugu
May 27 17:09:19 2013 dhcpd: if DELL1-DESTEK.meb.gov.tr IN A rrset doesn\'t exist add DELL1-DESTEK.meb.gov.tr 21600 IN A 10.6.1.250: timed out.
May 27 17:09:19 2013 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.6.1.250 (10.6.1.1) from 00:1c:23:b5:da:71 (DELL1-DESTEK) via eth4
May 27 17:09:19 2013 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.6.1.250 to 00:1c:23:b5:da:71 (DELL1-DESTEK) via eth4
May 27 17:09:22 2013 dhcpd: karpuz-kabugu
May 27 17:09:22 2013 dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.6.1.250 via eth4
May 27 17:09:22 2013 dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.6.1.250 (00:1c:23:b5:da:71) via eth4
```

As you can see, my client is assigned with `10.6.1.250` however I am expecting an IP address between `10.6.1.10` and `10.6.1.99`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Dhcp statement `allow unknow-clients`, as sated in man pages only allows to get an IP address from clients, who do not have a `host` declaration in config. And this is by default. So, my guess is to first remove such statement from pool declaration. And, second, try to add `deny` statemnt to that pool. Your pool config should be like this:

```
pool {
        range 10.6.1.10 10.6.1.99;
        allow members of "karpuz-kabugu";
      }

pool {
        range 10.6.1.100 10.6.1.250;
        deny members of "karpuz-kabugu";
     }
```